# How do I get boxfuse to detect that I'm using a MySQL database with my spring app using gradle?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, cloudcaptain

I followed the spring tutorial here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ and have it working. I then followed a tutorial on connecting to a MySQL DB and added the dependencies in the build.gradle. boxfuse doesn't seem to detect it.

```
MacBook-Pro-2 ~/work/test/server (develop) $ boxfuse info
Boxfuse client v.1.22.2.1149
Copyright 2016 Boxfuse GmbH. All rights reserved.

Account: ...

Info about ... in the dev environment:

App Type    : Single Instance (Elastic IP)
App URL     : 
DB Type     : No database
Logs Type   : No centralized logging
```

In my build.gradle file I just have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE")
        classpath 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.16')
}
```

Am I missing a step in order to make this work?

---

Edit:
I tried "boxfuse info" using the starter project tool at http://start.spring.io/ and had the dependencies for JDBC and MySQL selected:

[image]

Compiled to a jar and ran boxfuse in the build directory where the jar is. It still did not detect a DB.

Answer (score 0):

If your app was previously created with `db.type` set to `none` then you will need to destroy and recreate it to trigger the autodetection again and change the db type. To do this go to to your project directory and issue

`$ boxfuse destroy
$ gradle build
$ boxfuse create`

Boxfuse will then correctly pick up the MySQL driver and auto-provision a database in each environment upon deployment.